# Replace special characters sometimes doesn't work (MS Access/ VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm able to replace a lot of special characters, but sometimes it doesn't work. In most cases it seems, that it works. What could bei the reason?

```
outputstringf = Replace(outputstringf, "àª", "e")
```

either never works or at least doesn't work all the time.

```
outputstringf = Replace(outputstringf, "Ä±", "i")
outputstringf = Replace(outputstringf, "Ä>", "e")
```

both seem to work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your operating system transformes characters with accent according to your local settings (or local settings of your server). And that's why these charaters coming from your database or file or another media support, can not match with charaters written in your Replace() function.
I recommend you to run your code in debug mode for a case with these accents and see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed strings you can try this

```
outputstringf = Replace(outputstringf, Chr(A) & Chr(B), "e")
```

Where A and B are the character codes of the special characters you are looking to replace.